# operator ThisClass() causing stack overflow

Tags: c++, stack-overflow

I want to keep the class simple and not defined a constructor so i can do Pt data = {0, 5};
so i figured the best way convert Pt_t from a short to long or vice versa is to do something like this.

```
template <class T>
struct Pt_t
{
    T x, y;
    template <class T2> operator Pt_t<T2>() { Pt_t pt = {x, y}; return pt; }
};
```

The compiler doesnt like this and calls operator Pt_t on return pt; thus getting a stack overflow. How do i prevent this? the only solution i can think of is having Pt_t use constructors removing Pt_t pt = {1, 2}; which i prefer to keep if i can.

Comment: Please include the language as a tag on your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the unqualified Pt_t in your functions body is `Pt_t<T>`, but don't you want it to be `Pt_t<T2>`?  You'll need to explicitly qualify it.

Comment: Thank you, that was my error. For those who want to see code, the correct function is template <class T2> operator Pt_t<T2>() { Pt_t<T2> pt = {x, y}; return pt; }

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with C++, but are you declaring the right type in your method there?

Shouldn't it be `Pt_t<T2>` instead of just `Pt_t` ?